# Why is the link path showing up in brackets beside the anchor text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app in Rails. I'm using e text editor. I'm running windows. Just basic link_to with embedded ruby.

On all my links in every major browser, the link path is showing in brackets beside the anchor text.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up Now", signup_path %>
```

Resulting output is:

Sign Up Now (/signup)

Comment: could you provide an example for people to look at it i.e. a code snippet and the resulting output?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to pass ruby code inside a String?

Comment: what does your routes.rb file look like?

Comment: match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using blueprint. Try to fix print.css file, comment:

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was because fixed it by removing a line looking like:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the link path appears in brackets due to the following CSS lines inside `blueprint`:

In `blueprint/print.css`

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" ("attr(href)")";font-size:90%;}
```

and in `blueprint/src/print.css`

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {   
content: " (" attr(href) ")";  
font-size: 90%; }
```

Instead of removing those lines or commenting them out, I would recommend adding the `media` attribute while declaring the `print.css` stylesheet as follows:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %>
```

By doing so the styles are rendered only while printing the document and not on the screen.
There is more information about the `media` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp).

While referring to the other css files within blueprint, you should specify the `media` attribute as follows:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/plugins/fancy-type/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<\!--[if lt IE 8]>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie', :media => 'screen' %>
<\![endif]-->
<\!--[if lt IE 7]>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'basic_ie.css', :media => 'screen' %>
<\![endif]-->
```